# Do i need to use google tag manager with the latest google analytic web+app?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

i read how to implement the new google analytics web + app from here

[https://www.kristaseiden.com/step-by-step-setting-up-an-app-web-event-tag-in-gtm/](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/app-web)

In that article, the author uses Google tag manager to send a custom event and when i read the official 
[google docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/app-web)

The official google docs didn't mention anything about google tag manager, instead it uses this thing called gtag.js ( The global site tag )

Which method is suitable for the new google web+app analytic ??

Answer (score 0):

Both methods work fine for web+app properties. gtag.js method requires you to add all the necessary JavaScript to a page source code manually and GTM allows managing implementation without much of your developers time.
Behind the scenes, there's actually the same `gtag.js` library is used in both methods.